# DevTools Workspace not saving changes to Sass files

Tags: css, sass, google-chrome-devtools

I have watched [Paul Irish's video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x6qe_kVaBpg) of him making changes to CSS in DevTools, which were saved in his local Sass file too. To do that he set up a Workspace in Chrome then used Sass `--watch` flag with this path: `style.scss:style.css`.

I have a little bit different file structure than him. I have multiple Sass subfiles, which I import to my `main.sccs`. Then Sass compiler watches for changes in this file and compiles it to `main.css` (with a sourcemap by default).

So my file structure look like this:

```
project's root
|-- index.html
|-- css
   |-- main.css
   |-- sass
       |-- main.scss
       |-- theme
          |-- _variables.scss
          |-- _components.scss
          |-- _sctructure.scss
          |-- _menu.scss
```

And to compile Sass files I this path:

```
sass --watch sass/main.scss:main.css --style compressed
```

By him all worked well. By myself this works just partially because:

1. Changes made in `Elements Pane` are saved just to compiled `style.css` file on my drive. Sass files stay untouch.
2. Just changes made direct to Sass files in `Sources Pane` are saved to my local Sass files and to CSS file as well.

I want to make a change in `Elements Pane` and have it saved to my Sass files.

I can't make it work. I have tried to put all my styles in a single Sass file (just like Paul: one `style.scss` file compiled to `style.css`) but it didn't help. I have also tried to change a path in the Sass compiler and to watch a whole Sass directory. And still nothing. DevTools doesn't save changes made in `Elements Pane` to Sass files.

Any ideas how it can be achieved? I've looked for additional info on this topic but I didn't found a single solution, which would helped me in this regard.

Comment: I didn't know you can make chrome to convert sass and save it as css. Does it work with a regular file when you map a css file and try to save it? I used to use that feature but one day chrome cleared the css file and I've lost a week of work, since then I don't use it anymore...